# connecting to special email with python (3 credentials needed and not 2)

Tags: python, email, smtplib, imaplib

I want to connect to my university email from python- sending and receiving messages. The emails server is a gmail server, but when connecting manually I need to enter my email, ID number and password. Its the regular university identification- but that's the only way for getting into the email.
Here is part of what I tried:

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import webbrowser
import os

username = ""
password = ""
ID=""
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
imap.login(username,ID, password)
# ...
```

I get this error for the last line:

> TypeError: login() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I know that login() should take 2 parameters, but I didn't find any other solution for connecting.
I tried with smtplib and got the same error.
My questions is, how can I connect to my email, when 3 credentials are needed and not the regular 2?

thanks :)

Comment: Whatever the web interface presents as input form… how does that look at the SMTP/IMAP authentication level? Unless there's a specification for it, we can only guess…

Comment: what exactly is `ID` and where does it come from?

Comment: when trying to log in manually, gmail redirects to the university login page (where I need to type the email name, ID and password, the 3 credentials) and than from there I get redirect to gmail. the authentication system is the university one and not the regular google one. so the question is how to login from python with more than 2 login parameters, or there isn't a simple solution.

Comment: So Google is outsourcing the authentication via OAuth or similar to your university. That hardly allows us to draw conclusions what credentials you need to provide to log into IMAP directly. http://webapps.stackexchange.com or your university's admin might be the better contact here.

Comment: You probably need to implement OAuth, _or_, if your authentication system allows it, generate an [App Specific Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).  The latter is much easier if it works.

Comment: Thanks! the App Specific Password worked :)